# Get Spotify Stream Volume | Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, spotify, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to get the volume value of the Spotify Music Stream.
I am able to get it throw STREAM_MUSIC when Spotify is playing music from the Android device or while the Android device is connected to a bluetooth speaker.

But when I'm streaming from the Android device to my Spotify App on the Smart TV/TV Streamer, Android is creating a new volume stream called: "Spotify" (as in the picture)
How can I get this value?

[Picture of Volume Streams on my Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4azn.png)

Please help me understand how can I get the volume of this stream..
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a stream, the song is not really playing on the device and then being send to the TV. The TV itself is playing it and you are controlling it on the app. Similar to when I can control my pc's spotify from my laptop or my phone, definitely not streaming anything from one device to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is so difficult.

First, you have to use MediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)

But it needs NotificationListenerService.
Please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService
https://github.com/codechacha/NotificationListener

MyNotificationService.java

```
public class MyNotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyNotificationService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.notification.default_filter_types"
            android:value="1,2">
        </meta-data>
    </service>
```

Request permission

```
if (!permissionGrantred()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    startActivity(intent);
}


private boolean permissionGrantred() {
    Set<String> sets = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this);
    if (sets != null && sets.contains(getPackageName())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main code

```
MediaSessionManager msm = (MediaSessionManager)getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, MyNotificationService.class);
List<MediaController> list = msm.getActiveSessions(cn);
for (MediaController mc : list) {
    if (mc.getPackageName().equals("com.spotify.music")) {
        int spotifyVolume = mc.getPlaybackInfo().getCurrentVolume();
    }
}
```

or you can get it with callback

```
for (MediaController mc : list) {
    if (mc.getPackageName().equals("com.spotify.music")) {
        mc.registerCallback(new MediaController.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioInfoChanged(MediaController.PlaybackInfo info) {
                int spotifyVolume = info.getCurrentVolume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 안녕하세요! Is it possible to get the media playback info without allowing the app to access notifications? It's a complete privacy destructing action. Can't we just directly access the media session whenever it is available directly? As android 11 separated out the media playback notifications to quick settings, it should also allow to access the session without the notification permissions.

Comment: Hello, as I know there is no way.  MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions requires android.Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL permission. But it can be used from system app.